# is there a command to turn on keyboard lights?

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard, brightness

I just updated the BIOS of my friend's Dell Latitude E6420 (from A08 to A22)
and found out that the keyboard has a back light! There is a FN+Key which toggles thought the scales of brightness, maybe something like 0%, 25%, 50%,75%, 100% brightness per press.

I'm just wondering if there is a command that can  be given to just turn the keyboard back light on/off.

Comment: Does this work? `echo -n 100 > /sys/class/leds/chromeos\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness` to turn it on and `echo -n 0 > /sys/class/leds/chromeos\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness` to turn it off

Comment: nope, that doesnt work, and there is no option for chromeos. there is phy0-led/ though.

Comment: It works for my Dell in Ubuntu 16.04, but I have to become root first with `sudo su` as executing this command simply with sudo did not work.

Answer (score 2):

This is what is in the sub directory:

```
 echo -n 0 > /sys/class/leds/phy0-led/
brightness      max_brightness  subsystem/      uevent
device/         power/          trigger
```